# How to ask about the subject and objects in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, questions

I made up a sentence: "She feeds the shark fishes."

How to ask about the subject, the 1st object and the 2nd object?

Maybe:

1. Who feeds the shark fishes?
2. Who does she feed fishes?
3. What does she feed the shark?

Answer (score 1):

When I first saw your sentence I thought you were using 'shark fish' as the name of the creature! It would be better to say:

> She feeds the shark with fish, *or*
>
> She feeds fish to the shark.
>
> 2. Who does she feed fish to?
> 3. What does she feed the shark with?

Comment: You forgot "Who feeds the shark?"

Comment: Can I say "Who does she feed the shark with?", using "who" instead of "what"?

Comment: Only if she feeds a person to the shark! (or a named animal).

Comment: I don't in all honesty see much wrong with saying "She feeds the shark fishes".  It is only confusing because the shark is a fish. Had it been "She feeds the children porridge for breakfast" - no one could have any objection. It is perfectly idiomatic. Using the verb "feed" in this sense,   I consider "porridge" the direct object and "the children" an indirect dative case - she feeds it "to the children".

Comment: But of course if you said "She feeds the children with porridge" then "children" becomes the DO and porridge the "indirect".